Weird error on event dashboard. Undefined array key under fee
Recently upgraded to 5.80.1 and PHP 8.1 - all seems to be working well. However on the event dashboard I get the following error. I have cleared the caches multiple times. the file in reference seems to be Smarty v2 code, we are still on v2, so that could be the cause. I can't find the wordpress demo master to test.
Warning: Undefined array key 3989 in /home/prinyc/www/www/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%FE/FEB/FEB92208%%Selector.tpl.php on line 17
(no fee)
Line 17:

?>_tpl_vars['row']['participant_id']; ?> "odd-row,even-row"), $this);?>_tpl_vars['row']['event_id']; ?>'; ?>_tpl_vars['single']): ?>_tpl_vars['context'] == 'Search'): ?>assign('cbName', $this->_tpl_vars['row']['checkbox']); ?>'; ?>_tpl_vars['form'][$this->_tpl_vars['cbName']]['html']; ?>'; ?>'; ?>_tpl_vars['row']['contact_type']; ?> 'civicrm/contact/view','q' => "reset=1&cid=".($this->_tpl_vars['row']['contact_id'])), $this);?>_tag_stack[] = array('ts', array()); $_block_repeat=true;smarty_block_ts($this->_tag_stack[count($this->_tag_stack)-1][1], null, $this, $_block_repeat);while ($_block_repeat) { ob_start(); ?>_tag_stack[count($this->_tag_stack)-1][1], $_block_content, $this, $_block_repeat); }  array_pop($this->_tag_stack); ?>'; ?>_tpl_vars['row']['sort_name'])) ? $this->_run_mod_handler('purify', true, $_tmp) : smarty_modifier_purify($_tmp)); ?>'; ?> 'civicrm/event/info','q' => "id=".($this->_tpl_vars['row']['event_id'])."&reset=1"), $this);?>_tag_stack[] = array('ts', array()); $_block_repeat=true;smarty_block_ts($this->_tag_stack[count($this->_tag_stack)-1][1], null, $this, $_block_repeat);while ($_block_repeat) { ob_start(); ?>_tag_stack[count($this->_tag_stack)-1][1], $_block_content, $this, $_block_repeat); }  array_pop($this->_tag_stack); ?>'; ?>_tpl_vars['row']['event_title'])) ? $this->_run_mod_handler('purify', true, $_tmp) : smarty_modifier_purify($_tmp)); ?>'; ?>_tpl_vars['contactId'] )): ?> 'civicrm/event/search','q' => "reset=1&force=1&event=".($this->_tpl_vars['row']['event_id'])), $this);?>_tag_stack[] = array('ts', array()); $_block_repeat=true;smarty_block_ts($this->_tag_stack[count($this->_tag_stack)-1][1], null, $this, $_block_repeat);while ($_block_repeat) { ob_start(); ?>_tag_stack[count($this->_tag_stack)-1][1], $_block_content, $this, $_block_repeat); }  array_pop($this->_tag_stack); ?>('; ?>_tag_stack[] = array('ts', array()); $_block_repeat=true;smarty_block_ts($this->_tag_stack[count($this->_tag_stack)-1][1], null, $this, $_block_repeat);while ($_block_repeat) { ob_start(); ?>_tag_stack[count($this->_tag_stack)-1][1], $_block_content, $this, $_block_repeat); }  array_pop($this->_tag_stack); ?>'; ?>'; ?>assign('participant_id', $this->_tpl_vars['row']['participant_id']); ?>_tpl_vars['lineItems'][$this->_tpl_vars['participant_id']]): ?><?php $_from = $this->_tpl_vars['lineItems'][$this->_tpl_vars['participant_id']]; if (($_from instanceof StdClass) || (!is_array($_from) && !is_object($_from))) { settype($_from, 'array'); }$this->_foreach['lineItemsIter'] = array('total' => count($_from), 'iteration' => 0);


